# math.random(1, 100) is only giving me decimals

Tags: lua

I am making a program that requires a person to guess a randomly generated number. But this is impossible as the computer is only generating extremely long decimals. Is there a way for math.random(1, 100) to only generate whole numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a free script writing service. Your own research and code attempts are expected. Edit the question to include your code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Based on the documentation, math.random(1,100) already gives an integer (whole number) result.  Can you show some code of how you are using it so we can see if the problem is elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
function round(num, numDecimalPlaces)
  local mult = 10^(numDecimalPlaces or 0)
  return math.floor(num * mult + 0.5) / mult
end
```

Result:

```
round(1023.4345, -2) = 1000
round(1023.4345, 2) = 1023.43
```